# Query for SQL Server to find out average and maximum connected users

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to find out with a query how many users are connected in average to SQL Server and how many users are maximum connected at one time to SQL Server?

(I ask this to find out if I exceed the client access icence. )

Example for a result of a query would be 3 columns `Database`, `Max. Connections (today)` and `Average connections (today)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get how many connections are made today using current DMV's..But you can get total open  connection count so far for each database..

```
select 
db_name(dbid) as databasename,
count(*)
 from sys.sysprocesses
where dbid>0
group by dbid
```

if you are differentiating connection strings using Program name,you also can further segregate by client as well

```
select 
    db_name(dbid) as databasename,
    count(*) as cnt,program_name
     from sys.sysprocesses
    where dbid>0
    group by dbid,program_name
```